# How to get the size of a safe area?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

To get the safe area size in flutter, you can use the **'MediaQuery'** class. Here an example of how to get the size of safe area.

```
class SafeAreaExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const SafeAreaExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double safePadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

I tried to add pandding on top but, that padding is not working in all device than i try to find some solution.

Comment: Stop using MediaQuery.  Use LayoutBuilder.  It gives you what space is left.  Exactly what you need to know for your layout decisions.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily by using `MediaQuery.paddingOf(context)` like this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  double safePadding = MediaQuery.paddingOf(context).top; // using this to get padding
  return const Placeholder();
}
```

You shoud use `SafeArea` widget instead of add top padding. In default, this widget also add padding on bottom, left and right. You can remove its by adding parameters `bottom`, `left` and `right`.

```
class SafeAreaExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const SafeAreaExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      left: false,
      right: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: // Adding your widget here
    );
  }
}
```